# bootstrap fill empty space with columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to simulate a grid using bootstrap, I have a slight problem with placing one of the columns.

I have tried messing around with placement of the divs and offsets/pulls but with no luck.

To clarify what I would like to achieve, in the middle column there should be three blocks of the same height, at the moment there is a gap in the middle. Columns should fill available space if possible. Similar to below (not to scale).

[image]

http://www.bootply.com/KeQzWKbzPG

css

```
.grid-item--height2 { height: 202.5px; }
.grid-item--height5 { height: 405px; }
.grid-item--height7 { height: 607.5px; }
.tile {border:2.5px solid white; }
.blue-background {background-color:blue;}
.orange-background {background-color:orange;}
```

html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-5 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center">

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center">

      </div> 

      <div class="col-md-2 grid-item--height2 orange-background tile text-center">

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height7 blue-background tile text-center">

      </div>



      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center">

      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height5 blue-background tile text-center">

      </div>


        <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center">

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center">

      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center ">

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wat exactly is the issue here? Do you really need heights to be in that same order?

Comment: @Jay Thank you for letting me know. I have also included the css and html in the question itself

Comment: @Shivi unfortunately yes the design needs to be in that order. I have managed to get it all together like this http://www.bootply.com/BvOfj7PklO but the higher ups werent happy with the layout

Comment: @Valeklosse: so, what exactly do u want here..?? the last three should fall together? or u want the first grid in last column to fall beneath the second grid of second column. What exactly do we need to achieve?

Comment: @Shivi if possible the middle column to have three blocks of the same height, basically where the gap in the middle is, should be filled, and as you can see I have a column right at the bottom out of place. In a sense, columns should fill available space if possible.

Comment: I have added an sample layout of what I want to achieve, with what I have already I feel close to the desired result but just missing crucial piece of information.

Comment: Does this help? hhttp://www.bootply.com/LKWPlNHti9

Comment: Thats perfect. It now seems obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this plunk helped solve the issue.

http://www.bootply.com/LKWPlNHti9

Answer (score 1):

**Valeklosse**, have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kjaho6m/1/embedded/result/)**.
Is this what you are trying to achieve here, when you say all 3 blocks of the same height should be in the middle column?

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="col-md-5 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-2 grid-item--height2 orange-background tile text-center">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height7 blue-background tile text-center">
        </div>

    <div class="row col-md-4">  

        <div class="col-md-12 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center"> 
        </div>   
        <div class="col-md-12 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center"> 
        </div>

    </div> <!-- End Row--> 

        <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height5 blue-background tile text-center">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 grid-item--height2 blue-background tile text-center ">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End Row-Fluid-->
</div> <!-- End Container-Fluid-->
```